# Python Graphing Assitance

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

To whomever,

Having been given a data set of a few parameters (wavelength and 4 stokes parameters) I thought that I had set up everything correctly. However that is seemingly because when trying to get a graph I have the error of

`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`

I do not entirely understand what it means by *first dimension* but I do assume I've parameterized something wrong. A bit of preface is that I am given a collection of files that have data on wavelengths and stokes parameters (there are four of these: I Q U V) and to form graphs relating each stoke parameter to the wavelength.

Code-wise this is what we are looking at

**base**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants as c
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import re
split_on_spaces = re.compile(" +").split
```

**array listings**

```
WL = np.array([])
SI = np.array([])
SQ = np.array([])
SU = np.array([])
SV = np.array([])
```

**data sorting**

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Schmidt\\Desktop\\Python\\Homework_4\\CoolStuffLivesHere\\stokes_profiles_0.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=split_on_spaces(line.strip())
        if len(data) == 0:
            continue
        if len(data) != 5:
            sys.stderr.write("BAD LINE: {}".format(repr(line)))
            continue
        WL = np.append(WL, float(data[0]))
        SI = np.append(SI, data[1])
        SQ = np.append(SQ, data[2])
        SU = np.append(SU, data[3])
        SV = np.append(SV, data[4])
```

**plotting**

```
plt.plot(WL,SI)
plt.show()
```

There error again is `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`. What do I need to insert into my file in order to correct this. Added bonus but not necessary, how would I get 4 graphs onto one display when executed? [For example, something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfiaE.png)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like x and y only have one dimension if I read your example correctly. If you delete one of the `WL = np.append(WL, float(data[0]))` statements, I think your code will work (but I can't really test it since I don't have access to your file).

If you delete one of the `WL = np.append(WL, float(data[0]))`, though, I can at least assure you that WL and SI will have the same length (so it has a good chance of plotting correctly).

Comment: Yeah i noticed that as I was typing this and edited that immediately, must've forgotten to minus it out in the post. Also that worked, forgive my stupidity

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are passing arrays with different sizes (more specifically different lengths) to matplotlib. When looking at your code we see that you are trying to plot both `WL` and `SI` which are not of the same length.

If you look closely at your "data sorting" section you will see that you have duplicated a line of code:

```
WL = np.append(WL, float(data[0]))
WL = np.append(WL, float(data[0]))
SI = np.append(SI, data[1])
```

Because you're using the singleton append method, the contents in `data[0]` is appended to `WL` twice per loop iteration, yet `data[1]` is only appended to `SI` single time. This means that `WL` is going to end up being twice the length of `SI` and thus a dimensional mismatch.

Multiple graphs in a figure can be accomplished using the matplotlib `subplots()` method as described [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html). A simple example might look like this:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
axarr[0].plot(x, y)
axarr[1].plot(x, z)
```

Comment: Yeah I must've not realized that, forgive the slip. Also thanks for the multiple graphs link.

Comment: Using 

`f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axarr[0, 0].plot(WL, SI)
axarr[0, 0].set_title('Axis [0,0]')
axarr[0, 1].scatter(WL, SQ)
axarr[0, 1].set_title('Axis [0,1]')
axarr[1, 0].plot(WL, SU)
axarr[1, 0].set_title('Axis [1,0]')
axarr[1, 1].scatter(WL, SV)
axarr[1, 1].set_title('Axis [1,1]')`

it yields

`<matplotlib.text.Text at 0xdff121a9b0>`

What does this mean?

Comment: I think you need to call plt.show() otherwise you won't see the graph. When you see anything looking like this `<module.class at 0x...>` you're attempting to print out an object without a `_repr_()` method, so it just prints the type and address of the object. Also, I'm trying to build up my reputation on SO, so could you please accept the answer if it worked for you? :) Thanks!